# htaccess subdomain creating issue

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

my requirement is to have URL

```
www.subdomain.example.com/file1.php
```

which should point to

```
www.example.com/router.php?d=subdomain&f=file1.php
```

Similarly when i hit

```
www.subdomain2.example.com/file2.php
```

which should point to

```
www.example.com/router.php?d=subdomain2&f=file2.php
```

I have tried many ways but I am not able to achieve my goal.

I written below Rule but its giving internal server error.

I am very new to htaccess, please guide me how to resolve the issue.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+)\.jol-tributes\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)($|/) /router.php?d=%2%&f={REQUEST_URI} [PT,L,NC]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+)\.jol-tributes\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ router.php?d=%1&f=%{REQUEST_URI} [PT,L,QSA]
```

Comment: it works but when i print $_GET['d'] it gives me extra %

Comment: I want to learn htaccess can u teach me? If u want to charge I am ready.

Comment: I had a typo, removed extra `%` now. For learning .htaccess I suggest this good tutorial: http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php and then http://askapache.com I don't charge for anything on SO. You can ask me any question about it.